# Getting an error "Attempted to load class "LiipImagineBundle" from namespace "Liip\ImagineBundle". while setting up Liip in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, bundles

I'm trying to set up Liip for Symfony 4, here are the documentation pages:

https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/installation.html

I have already ran the `composer require liip/imagine-bundle` command, here is what my liip.yml file looks like:

liip_imagine :

```
# configure resolvers
resolvers :
    # setup the default resolver
    default :
        # use the default web path
        web_path : ~
# your filter sets are defined here
filter_sets :
    # use the default cache configuration
    cache : ~
    # the name of the "filter set"
    my_thumb :
        # adjust the image quality to 75%
        quality : 75
        # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
        filters :
            # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
            # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
            thumbnail  : { size : [120, 90], mode : outbound }
            # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
            # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
            background : { size : [124, 94], position : center, color : '#000000' }
```

I have a file config\routes\imagine.yml file that looks like:

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

Here is my \config\bundles.php file:

`< ?php`

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Aws\Symfony\AwsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];

I tried putting `Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle::class => ['all' => true]` to my bundles.php file but that didn't work.

Would anyone be able to tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What about joining Symfony Slack https://symfony.com/slack-invite? Maybe better than asking question after question here

Comment: Hi Mark, I just got an e-mail saying "We received an attempt to create an account for brent@heigoldinvestments.com on Symfony Devs, but this account already exists. "  What is the official name of the slack room?

Comment: I found it, symfony-devs.slack.com, but apparently the admin has to add my e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

you should put this configuration in the  'config/routing.yml' and not in 'config/packages/framework.yml'

Answer (score 0):

SF don't see liip  bundle , it's mostly cache problem

First  of  all

You need   to add bundle in bundles.php

And  afer  that  remove  whole  content  of  /var/cache  dir ( not  by  bin/console  but  remove it  manually  )

Comment: Hi Michal I still get the following error: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: Bundle "LiipImagineBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled.

Comment: Do you have source code on git or something? Can you show it to me ?

Comment: Hi Michal, I don't want to expose the source code publicly, is there any way I can send it to you privately?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Symfony Flex ?
If you use it, you should have a file named config/routes/imagine.yaml containing the following :

```
_liip_imagine:
resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

Moreover, you imported routing.xml instead of routing.yaml in your configuration...

And yes, you should add this line to your config/bundles.php file :

```
Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Comment: Hi Florian, I now get the following error:  Attempted to load class "LiipImagineBundle" from namespace "Liip\ImagineBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed in file composer.json:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.0.*",
```

After that enter this command in sandbox folder:

```
composer update
```